# Estou com um problema com padding/ margin

Tags: css

css code:

```
.row
{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/faq.png); 
    background-position: top center;
    height:auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    color: #000000;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.row h2
{
color: #e2aba7;
font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 48px;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.row p
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    font-family: Oswald;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.faq .faqq
{

    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/faqq.png);
    position: relative;
    height:97px;
    width: 97px;
    margin: auto;


}
```

html code :

```
<section class="faq">
            <div class="row">
                        <h2>FAQ</h2>
                        <p>Nós da SecureElobosting percebemos que muitos sites de ELOJOB tiveram seus dados vazados por hackers, muitos clientes tiveram seus emails vazados e consequentemente tiveram suas contas banidas do LEAGUE OF LEGENDS. Foi por isso que nós da SecureJob criamos esse sistema de segurança chamado PMD. Mas afinal, o que é a segurança PMD? PMD significa Pendrive – Messenger- Description. Usamos um messenger criptografado para troca de informações (planos PREMIUM e SJBOOST), pendrive para armazenar o MÍNIMO de suas informações, sem manter NADA online, Sendo assim, se um de nossos boosters ou administradores sofrerem ataques em seus computadores, nenhuma informação sua correrá riscos, tudo estará armazenado em um pendrive, sendo imediatamente deletado após a efetuação do seu elojob.</p>
            <div class="faqq">
            <img scr="images/faq.jpg"/>

            </div> 
            </div>

    </section>
```

como a imagem está:
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom eu queria subir o ícone do FAQ, mas já tentei de tudo e não vai..

Comment: Posta o html também!

Comment: opa mano vou responder postando o html

Comment: pronto mano postei

Comment: deixa ver se intendi, você quer subir é o simbolo do faq em um circulo né? se for isso, você ta usando no .row p (margin-bottom: 40px;) que está fazendo ele descer 40px; diminuindo isso ele ira subir, mas o tamanho da row em height ira diminuir também, solução: você pode setar um tamanho fixo para o height da row que atualmente é auto!

Comment: @GabrielCosta já tentou modificar a propriedade Top da imagem com valor negativo? `Top: -20px;` por exmplo.

Comment: opa eu conseguir vlw, vcs poderiam me dizer oq estou errando para deixar esse icone qnd clicar ir para a pagina?  codigo em html :   <div class="faqq">
  <a href="index.html">
        <img scr="images/faq.jpg"/>
   </a>
        </div>

Comment: tou tentando e nada :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O melhor neste caso é adicionar um `padding-bottom` na `row`, que irá criar um espaçamento adequado entre o ícone e a borda inferior da `row`. Como o `h2` já possui `margin` nativo, basta colocar nele um `margin: 30px 0;` para dar um espaçamento entre ele e o texto em `<p>` e o topo da `row`.

Veja a baixo o CSS corrigido. As linhas comentadas você pode apagar e informei também as linhas que adicionei:

```
.row
{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/faq.png);
    background-position: top center;
    height:auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    color: #000000;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;

   /*linha adicionada*/
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.row h2
{
   color: #e2aba7;
   font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   font-size: 48px;
   text-align: center;
   /*padding-bottom: 30px;*/

   /*linha adicionada*/
   margin: 30px 0;
}
.row p
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    font-family: Oswald;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    /*padding-bottom: 30px;*/
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.faq .faqq
{

    overflow: hidden;
   background: url(../images/faqq.png);
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
    height:97px;
    width: 97px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

> Outro erro está em `<img scr="images/faq.jpg"/>`, onde `scr` não
>   existe. O correto é `src`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá Gabriel no seu código que estiliza o a tag p tem um padding-bottom de 30px e um margin-bottom de 40px.

Se você diminuir esse valor o icone da faq que esta logo em baixo sobre automaticamente.

Comment: obg mano eu já consegui eu só botei ummargin: auto;
 margin-bottom: 35px;

Comment: e foi, como eu não sei , mas foi kk'